# How to show data from database then display it using telerik radlistview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radlistview

i am using the following code:

```
  selectQuery("select * from tbl_drivers_cashadvance")
        While dr.Read
        Dim lvl As Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewDataItem
        lvl = New Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewDataItem(New String(dr("full_date").ToString() + dr("amount").ToString() + dr("reason").ToString() + dr("encoded_by").ToString()))
        ViewDriver.lvCashAdvance.Items.AddRange(New Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewDataItem() {lvl})
end while
```

but it doesn't display anything.. Please help. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Have a look at this demo (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/migration/defaultcs.aspx). The entire functionality is achieved with the code on the HTML side. It is a good start.

Comment: i am using vb.net.. that is asp?